# Can ayone help me in solving the below Problems of probability distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution

Patients arrive randomly and independently at a doctor's surgery from
8·0 A.M. at an average rate of one in Five minutes.The waiting room holds 2
persons. What is the probability that the room will be full when the doctor
arrives at 9·0 A.M.?

Answer is 53.84%

I have tried Poisson distribution with parameter as 12/Hour? and i am getting like 99% as answers.

Comment: Are you sure that the waiting room holds only $2$ persons? If the waiting room would hold $12$ persons, a Poisson distribution with $\lambda = 12$/hour would result in the probability of the answer (i.e. $0.5384$). This is the probability that at least $12$ persons arrived up to 9 am.

Comment: YES thanx for the answer i checked it out using cumulative poisson distribution table, The Waiting room must hold 12 person in order to get 53.84% as answer. But in the book it is really 2 person in waiting room, maybe the printing mistake.Again thans for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. It is likely a typo in the book, yes.